# Google sheets function : Filter records by multiple condition

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets : Sheet1 has large number of records with columns Firstname, Lastname and Company. Another Sheet2 has same columns but small set of records. I want only those records from sheet1 which have a matching firstname and lastname in sheet2 but company is different. How can I achieve this with help of a formula? (it has to be scale-able).
E.g.
Sheet1

```
Firstname   Lastname    Company
John         Doe         ABC
Jon          Smith       XXX
Dan          S.          XXX
John         Davies      XXX
```

Sheet2

```
Firstname   Lastname    Company
John        Davies      ABC
Jon         Smith       XXX
```

Expected output :

```
Firstname   Lastname    Company
John        Davies      XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula:

```
=SORT(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ARRAYFORMULA(E2:E&" "&F2:F&" "&C2:C),ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&" "&B2:B&" "&C2:C),1,0))," ")),""),1,false)
```

Comment: Thankyou. The formula works with this data but if I shift row 10 down and add a new row with firstname that does not appear in table1 (row2 to row6), the result is #N/A. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You need to change the range in the formula per your dataset, share your sheet  or some screen-shot so that it can be answered accordingly if you need to cover full column then use something like this `A2:A`, I hope you need to filter consider firstname and lastname both

Comment: Sure, sharing the sheet url : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MbTIzqHjTg2zyaVpCtNK8Sw0fkWb_PJKY5iD1-3GViE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you see, there is a match for John Davies and John Smith

Comment: no I left a comment on the sheet. The result seems incorrect with new formula. Anyway, I solved it using script. Thanks for your help